# Web deployment task failed...Publish Azure Function in Visual Studio

Tags: function, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have published my function in Portal.And it's ok.When I edit in my function in visual studio and publish again,I got this error.

*Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("xxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service*

I read some topic and they provided me some treatment.One of them is add
"MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES = 1" in Application settings.But it don't work :'(.Maybe I try publish it later and it publish successfully.But when I edit, it will get this error again .
Tks for read.

Comment: I try to turn off proxy and it will fix it

Comment: Could you post your solution as answer to help others?

Comment: I will do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to turn off proxy and it will fix it